# package with _root_ breaks the scala compiler inside eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala

I was refactoring the package structure inside a scala project with eclipse.  In the middle of this I used a package statement with `_root_`, like this

```
package _root_.com.workday.foo.bar
```

Now my eclipse project will not build although I can still build everything in the command line.  The problem is that all my `com.*` imports are broken

```
import com.workday.some.thing.Else
```

The error is:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - object workday is not a member of package      com.workday.foo.bar.com
    - object workday is not a member of package      com.workday.foo.bar.com
```

It appears that it is trying to find all imports relative to the package statement at the top of each source file.

I have removed the `_root_` from my package and tried to clean my project and the workspace.  I have also tried changing the scala compiler from "sbt" to "refined" and back but to no avail

Does anyone know how to kick the eclipse scala compiler back on track???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question so quickly, but I discovered the problem.

I had a sub package defined in the middle of a source file that contains various mock classes, this sub package had been changed to `com.workday.foo.bar.messaging` so it made `com`a sub package of `com.workday.foo.bar` resulting in a package of `com.workday.foo.bar.com.workday.foo.bar.messaging`

Comment: The lesson I learned from this is to not put classes from different packages in the same source file, even if they are mock classes only use by tests in that file.